# How ignore fetch lazy when serialize object with springboot and entitygraph

Tags: java, spring-boot, jpa

I Have one entity with entityGraph, just like this:

```
@NamedEntityGraphs({
    @NamedEntityGraph(
            name = "order.grid",
            attributeNodes = {
                    @NamedAttributeNode(value = "id"),
                    @NamedAttributeNode(value = "name"),
                    @NamedAttributeNode(value = 'cars',subgraph = "cars-subgraph")
            },
      subgraphs = {
        @NamedSubgraph(
          name = "cars-subgraph",
          attributeNodes = {
            @NamedAttributeNode("cars")
          }
        )
      }
    ),
@NamedEntityGraph(
            name = "order.all",
            attributeNodes = {
                    @NamedAttributeNode(value = "id"),
                    @NamedAttributeNode(value = "name"),
                    @NamedAttributeNode(value = "houses",subgraph = "houses-subgraph"),
                    @NamedAttributeNode(value = 'cars',subgraph = "cars-subgraph")
            },
      subgraphs = {
        @NamedSubgraph(
          name = "cars-subgraph",
          attributeNodes = {
            @NamedAttributeNode("cars")
          }
        ),
@NamedSubgraph(
          name = "cars-subgraph",
          attributeNodes = {
            @NamedAttributeNode("houses")
          }
        )
      }
    )
})
    public class Order{
      private int id;
      private String name;
     @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL,fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
      @JoinColumn(name="car_id")
      private List<Car> cars;
      @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL,fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
      @JoinColumn(name="home_id")
      private List<House> houses;

    }
```

So When I execute in my repository the method with :

```
  @EntityGraph(value = "order.grid", type = EntityGraph.EntityGraphType.FETCH)
```

he returns only the cars itens, but when the springboot serialize(in my RestController) the object he fetch the homes too, and I don`t wanna to execute another sql, how can I fix this? 
But If I execute the entityGraph with order.all he should return all properties.

tks

Comment: Does changing the fetch type to `FetchType.EAGER` solve it?

Comment: I only wanna to bring the homes property if I execute the method with the order.all entitygraph